# Angular not recognizing jQuery after dependency move from package.json to bower.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, npm, browserify

To start, I had `angular`, `angular-bootstrap`, and `jquery` in `package.json` and everything is compiled via `browserify`.

```
// package
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.2",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4"
}
```

`angular-bootstrap` does not have anything higher than 0.12.2 in NPM, so I switched ng-bootstrap over to `bower.json`

```
// bower
"dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.4"
}
```

And added aliases in my `package.json`

```
// package
"browser": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js",
    "angular-bootstrap-tpls": "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"
}
```

After doing all this, `jQuery` is still available in the global namespace (accessible in the browser console), but `angular` directives no longer seem to pick use `jQuery`.

In my `directive`s if I log out the `element` or view its prototype (`element.__proto__`) I only see the basic `jqLite` methods available, not the full `jQuery` that was available before I made the switch to bower (and that I see when looking at `jQuery` in the console).

```
// directive
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(element);
        console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(element)); // <-- No jQuery methods available, only jqLite
    }; 
});
```

I tried a few different ways of shimming dependencies, but I don't think this is necessary given that `jQuery` is loaded via `package` and not `bower`.

```
// package
"browserify-shim": {
    "angular-bootstrap": {
        "depends": "jquery:jQuery"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated - not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: try putting jQuery at the top and make jQuery a dependency of angular not angular-bootstrap.  jQuery needs to load in page before angular in order for `angular.element` to use it

Comment: @charlietfl are you saying put jQuery at the top of the dependency hash?

Comment: just saying it needs to load before angular does to be able for angular to use it internally. So at top can't hurt

Comment: I managed the same problem by adding jquery only in bower dependencies (basic one without shim) + added a resolutions block to fix the version. Hope it helps

Comment: @benek This sounds promising - not sure what a resolutions block is and Google isn't returning anything illuminating - mind pointing me toward a resource on that topic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have and jQuery is rightly resolved on top of jqlite:

bower.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
}
```

package.json

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },

 "browser": {
     "jquery": "./bower_repo/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
  }
```